Carousel linked roll to the side independently
I have a page with multiple carousel rows, but whenever I click on the button "next" or "prev" to show the other items of the carousel it impacts all carousels, not only the clicked one.
I have tried separating them in partial views so each js is executed only in its context, but it is still the same problem.
I want to be able to see the next item and the previous independently from another
If possible I wanted the js to get only items inside the partial view, but if there's other solution I am open to hear
js:
$(document).ready(function () {
    const multipleItemCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExample')
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
        const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(multipleItemCarousel, {
            interval: false
        })

        var carouselWidth = $('.carousel-inner')[0].scrollWidth;
        var cardWidth = $('.carousel-item').width();

        var scrollPosition = 0;

        $('.carousel-control-next').click(function () {
            if (scrollPosition < carouselWidth - (cardWidth * 4)) {
                scrollPosition += cardWidth;
                $('.carousel-inner').animate(
                    { scrollLeft: scrollPosition },
                    600
                );
            }
        });

        $('.carousel-control-prev').click(function () {
            if (scrollPosition > 0) {
                scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
                $('.carousel-inner').animate(
                    { scrollLeft: scrollPosition },
                    600
                );
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(multipleItemCarousel).addClass('slide');
    }

});


HTML:

<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="card">
                @{
                    var firstCourse = Model.First();

                    <img src="@firstCourse.Image" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@firstCourse.Title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">@firstCourse.Description</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach (var course in Model.Skip(1))
        {
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="@course.Image" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@course.Title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">@course.Description</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>



I have included the HTML

Do the carousels have the same id? You may need to create them unique for each one so the selector only grabs the unique one you're wanting to impact.

Please include the corresponding html.

they do have the same Id, the idea is to use the partial "carousel" so I don't have to duplicate code

Each of the carousels should live in its own scope. Notice the use of $.find which finds elements that are children of the carousel.
$(document).ready(function() {

  // i'm assuming #carouselExample is the id of all your carousels
  const multipleItemCarousels = document.querySelectorAll('#carouselExample')

  multipleItemCarousels.forEach(function(multipleItemCarousel) {

    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
      const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(multipleItemCarousel, {
        interval: false
      })

      var carouselWidth = $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-inner')[0].scrollWidth;
      var cardWidth = $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-item').width();

      var scrollPosition = 0;

      $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-control-next').click(function() {
        if (scrollPosition < carouselWidth - (cardWidth * 4)) {
          scrollPosition += cardWidth;
          $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-inner').animate({
              scrollLeft: scrollPosition
            },
            600
          );
        }
      });

      $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-control-prev').click(function() {
        if (scrollPosition > 0) {
          scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
          $(multipleItemCarousel).find('.carousel-inner').animate({
              scrollLeft: scrollPosition
            },
            600
          );
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(multipleItemCarousel).addClass('slide');
    }
  })
});


Thank you goldman! that worked really well
